# Finalizar código en un Activity para que no se siga ejecutando

Tags: java, android, firebase

He estado probando un código que me haga un filtro entre dos tipos de usuarios, puse el filtro en el LoginActivity y este se ejecuta de manera correcta, me filtra los usuarios y los envía a Activities distintas, el problema es que cuando uso este código la aplicación queda muy pesada y cuando ejecuto un llamado a la Database desde cualquier nueva Activity, esta me crashea la app y me envía de nuevo al primer Activity señalándome este error...

```
I/Choreographer: Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Y este es el código del LoginActivity que me genera el error de arriba, ya que he probado con y sin este código y sólo cuando lo uso me genera el error. Es como que se siguiera ejecutando y relentizando la app...

```
if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            Database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            user_id = auth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
            Database.child("A_Usuarios").orderByChild("Uid").equalTo(user_id)
                    .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                               @Override
                                               public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                                   Iterator<DataSnapshot> items = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();
                                                   entries.clear();
                                                   while (items.hasNext()) {
                                                       DataSnapshot item = items.next();

                                                       if (item.child("TipoUsuario").exists()) {

                                                           TipoUsuario = item.child("TipoUsuario").getValue().toString();

                                                           if (TipoUsuario.equals("Empresa")) {
                                                               Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainEmpresa.class);
                                                               startActivity(intent);
                                                               finish();
                                                           } else {
                                                               Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                                               startActivity(intent);
                                                               finish();
                                                           }
                                                       }
                                                   }
                                               }

                                               @Override
                                               public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                               }
                                           }
                    );
        }
```

¿Cuál será el error?, espero puedan ayudarme, desde ya, muchas gracias por todo!

Comment: solo necesitas que se ejecute una vez no ?

Comment: Porque no solo agregas a la base de datos en el usuario un campo para tipo de usuario y cuando se inicie sesion se verifique que tipo de usuario es y asi mandarlo al activity correspondiente.

Comment: eso es lo que esta haciendo , guarda TipoUsuario , verifica si existe el hijo y luego obtiene el valor, si es empresa va al MainEmpresa, sino al MainActivity

Comment: Lo que agregas no es en realidad el error que cierra tu aplicación " The application may be doing too much work on its main thread" incluso esto puede mostrarse en el LogCat pero no provocaría cerrar la aplicación , te sugiero agregar el problema real. @MatíasNicolásNúñezRivas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El `addValueEventListener` va a estar escuchando por cada vez que la app cambie un valor en Firebase, yo te sugeriria que si el login es el filtro donde lleva al usuario a otro lado uses un `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`, este va a ejecutar solo una vez la consulta para llevar al usuario a la activity donde se requiera.

Algunos consejos

Fijate que si este error te aparece en un emulador , ese puede ser uno de los problemas , ya que es un emulador virtual y no un dispositivo fisico. Tiene sus limitaciones por que depende el hardware de la pc para su correcto funcionamiento.

Para solucionarlo, es necesario identificar los nodos en los que existe, o posiblemente puede suceder, una larga duración del procesamiento.

Podemos solucionar esto como te plantie arriba, solo haciendo el query una vez al db para filtrar los usuarios y no escuchar contasntemente por cambios.

Ademas cambiaria el while por un foreach sencillo para recuperar esos datos

```
  if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            Database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            user_id = auth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
            Database.child("A_Usuarios").orderByChild("Uid").equalTo(user_id)
                    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                                            for(DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                                                                if (snapshot.child("TipoUsuario").exists()) {

                                                                    TipoUsuario = snapshot.child("TipoUsuario").getValue().toString();

                                                                    if (TipoUsuario.equals("Empresa")) {
                                                                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainEmpresa.class);
                                                                        startActivity(intent);
                                                                        finish();
                                                                    } else {
                                                                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                                                        startActivity(intent);
                                                                        finish();
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }

                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                                        }
                                                    }
                    );
        }
```

Una recomendacion es que agregues un breakpoint desde el `if(auth.getCurrentUser() != null)` y verifiques que si ejecutando otra activity este bloque de codigo se sigue ejecutando, con el `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` no deberias de tener problema por que solo se va a llamar una vez al filtro.

Comment: Yo creo que esta es la respuesta, debe ser porque se ejecuta el código cada vez que hay un cambio en la db. Me fijaré más tarde al estar en mi pc. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda Gastón.

Comment: Ningun problema Matias, el addListenerForSingleValueEvent lo que va a hacer es solamente ir a la db una vez, chequear el usuario y mandarlo a la activity correspondiente, sin estar escuchando todo el tiempo por cambios en la misma, es la mejor opcionpara tu requisito